# “____ days in advance” exact meaning

Tags: time

What is the deadline for something due “[#] days/weeks/etc. in advance”?

For example, if something is required “seven days in advance” would providing it on Friday the week before be correct or too late (or somehow early) for the following Friday?

Comment: Such terminology is inevitably ambiguous.

Comment: Such terminology is bound to be imprecise as even scientists can't define instants precisely. When you take into account general language imprecision, office hours ... However, if a deadline alone is specified, handing in work to a specified recipient before the deadline must be acceptable.

Comment: @HotLicks I think you mean vague.

Comment: @Tuffy - I mean ambiguous.  The term can be interpreted several different ways.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to be *more* precise, but never perfectly precise. For example, one could narrow down the time frame by adding the idiom *to the minute*:

> Your application is due seven days in advance *to the minute*.

As Edwin Ashworth and Hot Licks have pointed out in the comments, anytime we say *a year/month/week/day in advance*, there will always be ambiguity in the time frame. On its own, there is no way to determine from *a day in advance* if we mean exactly 24 hours or if we mean any point in that given day.

Comment: That doesn't really deal with the ambiguity.

Comment: Are you referring to the ambiguity between something being due at a precisely given time vs. being due any time before or up to that time?

Comment: OP is asking about what 'seven days in advance / beforehand' actually means in terms of hrs / min / sec.

Comment: The ambiguity is with regard to fractions of a day.  If your interview is Wednesday at 10AM, does Tuesday at 1PM count as "one day before", when specifying when the application must be turned in?  Or does it imply before 10AM on Tuesday?  Or does it imply before closing time on Monday?  This is an inevitable ambiguity in this sort of time specification, and there is no common idiom which clarifies it.

Comment: One can use the idiom “to the minute” in this situation to be more precise about the time. A Google search of “in advance to the minute” brings up several examples of this usage. For example, from the University of Louisiana website: “EMS locks out reservations two weeks in advance to the minute.”